# How to persist form data after validations fail in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, submit

I'm having trouble keeping HTML form data that has been set on a webpage after I run validations through javascript. I've tried setting the data to what it was prior to the validations during the failed validation step but the form doesn't actually update till it completes this. I believe this is because when validations fail, I set `theForm.action = "this_page.html"`. This refreshes the page to it's original state (I think).

Here's the gist of my form:

```
<!--this_page.html-->
<form name="article" onsubmit="return submitArticle(this);" method="get">
    <select id="category" onchange="subCategory()">
        <option value="DEFAULT">Please Choose Category</option>
        <option value="Pick Me!">Pick Me!</option>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And the gist of the validations:

```
function submitArticle(theForm) {
    var cat = document.getElementById('category').selectedIndex;
    if (!cat){
        alert("Please fill out categories!");
        theForm.action = "this_page.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply prevent the form submission when the form is invalid?

Instead of `theForm.action = "this_page.html";` just do `return false;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use html 5 inbuilt validation instead of java script it will easily you can manage or make sure your validating function outside of document. Ready if you stick to current validation method